# Automate "ncvar_get"-reading of different variable names in NetCDF files

Tags: r, if-statement, automation, netcdf4

I have a NetCDF dataset with two climate scenarios (rcp & hist), both of them containing 25 files. Each file either contains data for the variable "pr", "tas", "tasmax", or "tasmin". I wrote a for loop to iteratively read the files of hist and rcp, read them with nc_open, extract the variable with ncvar_get and finally make a calculation in form of mean(abs(hist - rcp) to obtain the mean absolute distance between each pair of hist and rcp. The problem: as ncvar_get requires the exact variable name of the current file I wrote an if else block (see below) that shall find the variable name of the current file and apply it for ncvar_get. Running the code I obtain the following error:

```
[1] "vobjtovarid4: error #F: I could not find the requsted var (or dimvar) in the file!"

[1] "var (or dimvar) name: tas"

[1] "file name: /data/historical/tasmax_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_DMI-HIRHAM5_r3i1p1.nc" Error in vobjtovarid4(nc, varid, verbose = verbose, allowdimvar = TRUE) : Variable not found



 #Extract of the files in the hist list. Same file names in the rcp list, but different directory

    > hist.files.cl <- list.files("/historical", full.names = TRUE)

    > hist.files.cl

 [1] "/historical/pr_CNRM-CERFACS-CNRM-CM5_ALADIN53_r1i1p1.nc"           
 [2] "/historical/pr_CNRM-CERFACS-CNRM-CM5_ALARO-0_r1i1p1.nc"            
 [3] "/historical/pr_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_HIRHAM5_r3i1p1.nc"                   
 [4] "/historical/pr_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_RACMO22E_r12i1p1.nc"                 
 [5] "/historical/pr_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_RCA4_r12i1p1.nc"                     
 [6] "/historical/pr_MPI-M-MPI-ESM-LR_RCA4_r1i1p1.nc"                    
 [7] "/historical/pr_MPI-M-MPI-ESM-LR_REMO2009_r1i1p1.nc"                
 [8] "/historical/pr_MPI-M-MPI-ESM-LR_REMO2009_r2i1p1.nc"                
 [9] "/historical/tas_CNRM-CERFACS-CNRM-CM5_CNRM-ALADIN53_r1i1p1.nc"     
[10] "/historical/tas_CNRM-CERFACS-CNRM-CM5_RMIB-UGent-ALARO-0_r1i1p1.nc"
[11] "/historical/tas_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_DMI-HIRHAM5_r3i1p1.nc"              
[12] "/historical/tas_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_KNMI-RACMO22E_r12i1p1.nc"           
[13] "/historical/tas_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_SMHI-RCA4_r12i1p1.nc"               
[14] "/historical/tas_MPI-M-MPI-ESM-LR_MPI-CSC-REMO2009_r1i1p1.nc"       
[15] "/historical/tas_MPI-M-MPI-ESM-LR_MPI-CSC-REMO2009_r2i1p1.nc"       
[16] "/historical/tasmax_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_DMI-HIRHAM5_r3i1p1.nc"           
[17] "/historical/tasmax_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_KNMI-RACMO22E_r12i1p1.nc"        
[18] "/historical/tasmax_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_SMHI-RCA4_r12i1p1.nc"        


euc.distance <- list()


for(i in 1:length(hist.files.cl)) {

#Open ith file in list of hist files as well as in list of rcp files

  hist.data <- nc_open(hist.files.cl[i])   
  rcp.data <- nc_open(rcp.files.cl[i])

  if(grepl("pr", hist.data$filename)){
    hist.var <- ncvar_get(hist.data, "pr")
    rcp.var <- ncvar_get(rcp.data, "pr")
    }else if (grepl("tas", hist.data$filename)){
    hist.var <- ncvar_get(hist.data, "tas")
    rcp.var <- ncvar_get(rcp.data, "tas")
    }else if (grepl("tasmax", hist.data$filename)){
    hist.var <- ncvar_get(hist.data, "tasmax")
    rcp.var <- ncvar_get(rcp.data, "tasmax")
    }else{
    hist.var <- ncvar_get(hist.data, "tasmin")
    rcp.var <- ncvar_get(rcp.data, "tasmin")
    }
 #Converting temperature variable from K to °C: 

  if(grepl("tas", hist.data$filename)){

    hist.var <- hist.var-273.15
    rcp.var <- rcp.var-273.15
  }

 #Find for the ith rcp file with dim=(1,1,360) in the ith hist file with dim=(385,373,360) the grid point with the best fitting distribution (each grid point consists of a distribution of 360 time steps).The calculation may contain errors...

  euc.distance[[i]] <- apply(hist.var, c(1,2), function(x) mean(abs(rcp.var - x)))
  min_values <-  which(rank(euc.distance[[i]], ties.method='min') <= 10)
}
```

As cath highlighted the probable cause of the error, but the proposed approach to extract the part of interest (=variable name) from the filename does not work. I before tried to automate the extraction of the variable name by using stringr("filename",startposition, endposition) until I noticed that there is no sense in it, because each variable name (pr, tas, tasmax, tasmin) has another string length. What possibilities do you see for me?
Thank you a lot!

Comment: in fact "tas" is included in "tasmax" and that is surely why you encounter a problem. You'll have to be more precise in your `grepl` call. Probably you can extract the exact part that is of interest and then do only one call (as this part is exactly the variable name you want). Something like `keypart <- sub("regex", "what I need", hist.data$filename) ; hist.var <- ncvar_get(hist.data, keypart) ; rcp.var <- ncvar_get(rcp.data, keypar)`: one "block" instead of 4...

Comment: If you give us more info (see [ask] and [mcve]) it will be much more easier for us to help

Comment: Yes, your explanation makes sense! I yet tried to write a general function to extract the part of interest for each file automatically. I used e.g. stringr("filename", 55, 57), but I noticed that that doesn't make sense in my case, as due to the different length of the variable names "pr" has other indexes in the string than "tas", "tasmax", or "tasmin". I will edit my above issue and provide filenames etc. Thanks!

Comment: in your case `keypart <- sub("^([a-z]+)_.+", "\\1", basename(hist.files.cl))` (you'll get the vector of all keyparts corresponding to the filenames)

Comment: Great, that works! Thank you a lot Cath!

Answer (score 3):

To complete a bit my comment, if you need to operate on each file, you could do it at once, putting everything in a list.

So, first get the "keypart" for each file:

```
keyparts <- sub("^([a-z]+)_.+", "\\1", basename(hist.files.cl))
keyparts
# [1] "pr"     "pr"     "pr"     "pr"     "pr"     "pr"     "pr"     "pr"    
# [9] "tas"    "tas"    "tas"    "tas"    "tas"    "tas"    "tas"    "tasmax"
#[17] "tasmax" "tasmax"
```

Then you can use `lapply` to do what you need to do for every files at once:

```
my_res <- lapply(seq(keyparts), 
                 function(i){

         hist.data <- nc_open(hist.files.cl[i])   
         rcp.data <- nc_open(rcp.files.cl[i])

         hist.var <- ncvar_get(hist.data, keyparts[i])
         rcp.var <- ncvar_get(rcp.data, keyparts[i])

         if(keyparts[i]=="tas"){
           hist.var <- hist.var-273.15
           rcp.var <- rcp.var-273.15
         }


        euc.distance <- apply(hist.var, c(1,2), function(x) mean(abs(rcp.var - x)))
        min_values <-  which(rank(euc.distance[[i]], ties.method='min') <= 10)

        return(list(euc.distance=euc.distance, min.values=min.values))

                   })
```